# Half sectional views of Plummer block

Tags: mechanical-engineering, autocad

I am trying to assemble the parts of Plummer block and draw the half sectional views from the front as given [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ut.edu.sa/documents/10156/2181404/CW7%2B(Plummer%2BBlock)&ved=2ahUKEwi2tYnuy_TfAhVQWysKHZdFBjIQFjAIegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1Twfvx_Etvk0tGL6yqR9L8)

I am facing some trouble understanding a few sectional views. In this view [image]

I am unable to understand why there are two different radii R32 and R34 marked in the front view of base.

In this view [image]
I am unable to get why there are two different radii for brass shown R32 and R30. Also which component R38
represent in the front view.

Thanks.

Comment: I studied Plummer block from here https://youtu.be/Y-_LjEjyLhA

Answer (score 3):

The semicircle in that front view steps to a larger diameter for part of its length. See the top view for reference:

[image: front/top views showing double dimensions]

Again, looking at the alternate view for the second component shows where those radii come from:

[image: front/top views showing double dimensions]